# Ho do i make one to many relations in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list consisting of tuples like the following:

```
m = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4), ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'eta')]
```

how can i get the following output:

```
['c', 3, 'gamma']
```

need only for 'c' and not for rest of the elements a,b,d

Comment: You can transpose and index with `zip`: `list(zip(*m))[2]`

Comment: A bit more verbose: `[elm[2] for elm in m]`.

Comment: Thank you. Didnt know about zip function in .py

Comment: @f4l Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable 'm' contains list of tuples, there are 3 tuples considered as 3 items in list.

Variable 'n' takes each element (tuple) in the list and prints its value according to its index number.

```
m = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4), ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'eta')]
for n in m:
    print (n[2])
```

Comment: Could you add some commentary to explain your code and how it answers the question.

Comment: variable 'm' contains list of tuples,there are 3 tuples considered as 3 items in list. variable 'n' takes each element (tuple) in the list and prints its value according to its index number.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=[(1,2),('a','b')]
for t in m:
    print n[1]
```

Comment: Where is `n` defined?